# Is it possible to tell docker diff to ignore mounts?

Tags: docker

I find that `docker diff` is very useful to check what happend inside a container.

But I also find that docker diff will list mounted directory as `C` which means change in the output.

Following is a minimal test:

```
$ docker run --mount type=bind,source=$home/.config,target=$home/.config --name test -it ubuntu
(exit via ctrl+d)

$ docker diff test
C /etc
C /home
A /home/lc
A /home/lc/.config
```

There is some situation when I want to see the real changes and don't case about the mounted directories, is there any way to do that?

Comment: it doesn't look like it, because a volume mount would cause a change to the container at start. You could pipe the results to `grep` to ignore certain paths like `docker diff test | grep -v ".config"`

Comment: If `docker run -v ...:/container/directory` creates the `/container/directory` (as it does in your setup) then that is a change in the temporary container filesystem.  I'd suspect you wouldn't see this change if the mount point already exists in the base image; for example, mounting a data directory on to a well-known directory.